Why is my webkit slider thumb not styling itself?
I've been trying to get my chrome vertical sliders to work like they do in Firefox (which was weird to get working to begin with), though now that they work, I'm unable to style their thumbs at all.
I'm not sure if thats a problem with me not understanding webkit properties or some conflict with inherited properties, but everything I've read and tried online have not been getting me very far.
Thing's I've tried:

Vertical slider for chrome and moz
https://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html
https://dev.to/konnorrogers/creating-a-vertical-slider-using-input-typerange-1pen
I am trying to style the thumb of a range input but the webkit doesn't work
https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/
<input type="range"> style not applies to thumb when it is vertical (rotating the slider 90degrees is a pretty awful solution for responsive layout, and doing a totally custom JS slider seems like a really messy, hacky solution especially because it works out of the box in Firefox)

The webdocs page on ::-webkit-slider-thumb hasn't been too helpful either.
I have the repository here: https://github.com/GitVex/BardicInspiration/tree/111-sliders-are-not-working-on-chrome components > utils > VolumeSlider.tsx
Or I have the relevant code right here:
VolumeSlider.tsx
import React, { useMemo, useCallback } from 'react';
import { localVolumeControlEndType } from '../Player/states';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import styles from './VolumeSlider.module.css';

interface VolumeSliderProps {
    volumeControl: localVolumeControlEndType;
    className?: string;
    textBgColor?: string;
    height?: number;
}

const VolumeSlider = ({ volumeControl, className = '', textBgColor = '', height = 100 }: VolumeSliderProps) => {
    const uniqueId = useMemo(() => `volumeSlider${Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000)}`, []);
    const { localVolume, setLocalVolume } = volumeControl;

    const handleVolumeChange = useCallback(
        (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
            setLocalVolume(parseInt(e.currentTarget.value));
        },
        [setLocalVolume]
    );

    return (
        <div className={`${styles.container} ${className}`}>
            <input
                id={uniqueId}
                className={styles.slider}
                type="range"
                min="0"
                max="100"
                step="1"
                //@ts-ignore
                orient="vertical"
                value={localVolume}
                onChange={handleVolumeChange}
                style={{ height: `${height}px` }} // Inline style for dynamic height
            />
            <div style={{ height }}>
                <motion.p
                    className={textBgColor}
                    animate={{
                        y: height * (1 - localVolume / 100) + 0.12 * localVolume - 20,
                        transition: { ease: 'easeOut', duration: .5 },
                    }}
                >
                    {localVolume}
                </motion.p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default VolumeSlider;

VolumeSlider.module.css:
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 10%;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 4px;
}

.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
    appearance: slider-vertical; /* The problem may be with this? Maybe switching this to none will let me style it but not setting it to slider-vertical will make it not work */
    width: 5px;
}

/* ------------------ Firefox ------------------ */

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    appearance: none;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

/* ------------------ Chrome ------------------ */

.slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(37, 190, 39);
    border-radius: 2.5px;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    height: 36px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: red;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }

/* ------------------ MS Edge ------------------ */

.slider::-ms-thumb {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.slider::-ms-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background: #ccc;
    border-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
}
/* 
.slider:focus {
    outline: none;
} */


If anyone comes across this in the future, I managed this by using the material-ui sliders. Still couldn't figure out a custom solution without a library though.
